# Can you refer to a named enum as if it were anonymous in D?

Tags: enums, d

I'm doing a D bridge to a C library, and this has come up with the C code using typedef'd enums that it refers to like a constant, but can name it for function arguments and the like. Example:

```
enum someLongNameThatTheCLibraryUses
{
    A,
    B,
}
```

Currently, I must refer to it like so:

```
someLongNameThatTheCLibraryUses.A;
```

But I would rather:

```
A;
```

I could do this:

```
alias someLongNameThatTheCLibraryUses a;
a.A;
```

But I don't want to do that in the library module, so I'd have to do it where it's used, which would be annoying.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like type safety with anonymous enums, you can create a new distinct type using `typedef`, and use it as the base type of the anonymous enum. Example:

```
typedef int A;
enum : A
{
    a1,
    a2,
    a3
}

typedef int X;
enum : X
{
    x1,
    x2,
    x3
}

void main()
{
    A a;
    X x;
    x = a;  // Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (a) of type A to X
}
```

Comment: 40 minutes; I love this place.